Power Automate - Copy one SharePoint site to another but exclude a file type
So... I have an automated flow that copies files from a folder in one SharePoint site into a target folder in another site (same tenant). It is set to exclude a particular file type during copy using basically a for each loop.
However, because I only have the one loop, it only does it for the root folder. How do I get it to dynamically work through nested folders? The source folder will get more folders in the future, and I would like to set the flow to run once a day.
The flow looks kinda like this:
Manually trigger a flow (for testing the flow before automating it)
List folder

source site selected
source folder selected

Apply for each

"body" from List folder

Condition

file does not end with .pdf (for example)

If false, no action entered
If true, Copy File

Current Site Address entered
File to Copy: Id from List folder
Destination Site Address entered
Destination Folder entered
If Another File is Already There: Replace


It took me a while to get that bit to work, then I realised it wasn't iterating through the nested folders so the "pdfs" were still being copied.
Any ideas? Did I completely choose the wrong options in the flow?

So it sounds like you need to essentially duplicate the contents of a document library from one SharePoint site into another, excluding PDFs. The setup you have now is good all you really need to do is add another condition that checks whether the items is a folder or not, and then create the file/folder appropriately. Luckily, a recursive solution is not necessary.
The following is a general description of a flow that will copy all files (including folder structure and excluding PDFs) from one SharePoint site's document library to another SharePoint site's document library:

Your flow's trigger
Initialize varibale

Name = strTemplateLibraryName
Type = String
Value = <the name of the document library you are copying files from>


Initialize variable

Name = strTargetLibraryName
Type = String
Value = <the name of the document library you are copying files to>


Get files (properties only)

Site Address = <the URL of the site you are copying files from>
Library Name = strTemplateLibraryName


Apply to each

Input = outputs('Get_files_(properties_only)')?['body/value']


Condition (inside Apply to each)

items('Apply_to_each')?['{IsFolder}'] is not equal to true



The false branch of your Condition will be all iterations where the item is a folder and should have this structure:

Compose (FullFolderPath)

Inputs = items('Apply_to_each')?['{FullPath}']


Compose (FolderPath)

Inputs = last(split(outputs('FullFolderPath'), variables('strTemplateLibraryName')))


Create new folder

Site Address = <the URL of the site you are copying files to>
List or Library = <the document library you are copying files to>
Folder Path = outputs('FolderPath')



The true branch of your Condition will be all iterations where the item is a file and should have this structure:

Condition

whatever your existing condition is to check if the file is a PDF
if the file is not a PDF, continue steps below, else ignore


Compose (FullFilePath)

Inputs = items('Apply_to_each')?['{FullPath}']


Compose (FilePath)

Inputs = first(split(last(split(outputs('FullFilePath'), variables('strTemplateLibraryName'))),item()?['{FilenameWithExtension}']))


Get file content

Site Address = <the URL of the site you are copying files to>
File Identifier = items('Apply_to_each')?['{Identifier}']
Infer Content Type (parameter) = Yes


Create file

Site Address = <the URL of the site you are copying files to>
Folder Path = /variables('strTargetLibraryName')outputs('FilePath')
File Name = items('Apply_to_each')?['{FilenameWithExtension}']
File Content = body('Get_file_content')



When I made this flow a while back, I was referencing this guide that you might find helpful. It is difficult to write out flows on here so please let me know if you have any questions.

this looks great. However, what do I put in as the Source and Target library names? Is it the word "Documents" that the flow finds when using the GUI? Or is it the full url to the target folder that I want to copy from within the library?

Yes, the source and target variables would just be the name of your document library. This is often "Documents" or "Shared Documents" by default. These are used to correctly format paths when copying files/folders.

Thanks mate. I'm just getting back to trying this out again. I've run a test with just the folder creation before copying any files over and that works but it's copying from root to root. I am looking to copy sub folders from one to a sub folder from another rather than the whole library. Where would I put in the folder names that I want to copy from and to? I tried putting them into the variables but it threw an error.
